# Accessing outlets from different class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I'm not even 100% sure this belongs here, but I need some assistance.

Basically, I have 3 sets of files:
Storyboard Viewcontroller w/ ViewController
Nib > Controller
Nib > Controller

The storyboard tableviewcontroller loads one of the nibs as a table cell, the other is just a view that is added on to the top of the primary storyboard view.

To try to illustrate what I am doing, here is the code:

```
let pickerView = UINib(nibName: "DateTimePickerView", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as! DateTimePickerView

    let testFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 200)

    pickerView.frame = testFrame
    ReserveView.addSubview(pickerView)
    pickerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: pickerView, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .LeadingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).active = true

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: pickerView, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .TrailingMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).active = true

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: pickerView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .BottomMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).active = true
```

This adds the nib to the bottom of the view that is displayed. What I am trying to accomplish is this:

In the other nib that is loaded as the table cell: there are buttons, labels, etc that I want to interact with from the pickerView that is drawn on top of the view.

Hopefully this image can help clarify what I am trying to do and you can tell me why this is wrong.. because it doesn't feel like its the right way.

Ultimately, the "pickerView" will appear on button click, then hide when the user selects and confirms the date.

Here is the photo:
[image: Drawing of what I tried to describe]

Here is the actual project, so you can better see what I am trying to do:
[image: Actual Project SS]

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you have a storyboard that loads a nib with a tableView and cells in it as well as a nib with the picker view.

If your storyboard holds a reference to the tableview and the content it needs to change, you could use [closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) with the pickerview.

In your pickerview add the following:

```
var didChange: ((value: String)->())?
```

In your storyboard class add the following code:

```
func pickerDidChange(value: String) {
    debugPrint("The picker changed")
}
```

Where you initialise your picker view, add the following just above the `addSubview`:

```
pickerView.didChange = pickerDidChange
```

Now, in your `pickerDidChange` func you'll take the data you needed and apply it to the cells in the tableView, which you held a reference to.

In the pickerview you'll add the following in the onChange method:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if let didChange = didChange {
        didChange("something")
    }
}
```

If you would be using a `UIDatePicker` instead, then return a `NSDate` instead... which I guess would be more appropriate.

I hope I understood your question properly and this solves your issue.

Comment: I am kind of confused a little bit. In my IBAction for the change event, I am supposed to add that function pickerView. What do I call that with though? Right now, you're correct, it is an NSDate object. But I am just accessing it via the DateTimePicker's date property. `DateTimePicker.date`

Comment: Really, I need to pass that date Object, back to the VC that loads the pickerView xib file. The xib, however, has its own custom class of type UIView, I have the actual picker as an IBOutlet in that class. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: @Imperialized Did you get the problem solved or do you still need help?